# R8 gives warning while creating release android apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I saw warnings on google play that I need to turn on minifyEnabled. When I activate it, I get these warnings while compiling and the library I use for google play subscriber control is not working on released APK but it works fine on android studio emulator runtime.

```
Android Studio 4.1
Android Gradle Plugin: 4.1.0
Gradle: 6.7
```

I tried some proguard settings but they are not working.

```
> Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Missing class: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener

Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue
```

Comment: Seems it's expecting `ClassValue`, which is not present in Android 13 and below. Maybe you need to add `-dontwarn javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and `-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue` to your proguard config